# Postgres major version changes causes log in and data issues

Tags: linux, postgresql

I've recently update packages with `yum update` and it turns out a major version of PostgreSQL got updated from version `8` to version `11`. A colleague of mine who happened to be using Postgres told me he could not longer log in into the database.

Is it possible that a major release change locks him out of the database and changes the password?

I don't understand how an upgrade can cause such issue. Furthermore he told me he could not recover the tables and had to recreate everything from scratch. Isn't the case that tables in databases are written on disk? If you lose connection to a database you also lose the data?

Comment: You generally don't want to approach major version changes in Postgres without advance planning. These upgrades often require an explicit database migration step, because the underlying file formats are typically not compatible. I am highly surprised that `yum update` resulted in a major version change like this; most `yum`-based distributions wouldn't permit this sort of change without a major version change in the distribution version.

Comment: And that was RHEL. I accidentally did yum update and apparently screw  up his work

Comment: For what it's worth, I am **positive** that RHEL would not include a major postgres version update unless you have configured some third-party repositories (RHEL has the opposite problem: it typically lags several versions behind because it is targeting stability). It may be worth double checking your yum repository configuration.

Comment: There is  missing information here: 1) OS version 2) Exact Postgres versions. There where multiple 8.X major versionr. FYI, even the most recent 8.4 is 8 years past EOL so that is an issue in itself.  3) Have you verified that the Postgres server is actually running? 4) Have you verified whether both versions are still on the machine?